# Unparseable date at offset 25

Tags: java, date-format, parseexception

I'm having trouble fixing the issue. I'm trying to parse a date string `2013-05-23T19:00:00GMT-00` into the StandardFormat which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz` but I always get a ParseException at position 25.

```
    // Get a human readable format.
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateTime.getStandardFormat();

    // Subtract a full hour from the time passed in.
    final int HOUR_IN_MINUTES = 3600;
    DateTime dateTimeLess1Hour = aDateTime.minus(HOUR_IN_MINUTES, 0);

    // Convert the DateTime, less exactly one hour, to a string.
    String timeLess1String = dateFormat.format(DateTime.toDate(dateTimeLess1Hour));

    // Split the string to distinguish the time part
    String date = timeLess1String.substring(0, 10);
    String time = timeLess1String.substring(11);

    String[] hhMMss = time.split(":");

    String hourOnHourDate = date + "T" + hhMMss[0] + ":00:00" + hhMMss[2].substring(2);

    Date inDateFormat = null;

    // Convert the string into a Date object
    inDateFormat = dateFormat.parse(hourOnHourDate);

    // Convert the Date into a DateTime object.
    return new DateTime(inDateFormat);
```

The error message says Unparseable date: 2013-05-23T19:00:00GMT-00

Comment: Try using SimpleDateFormat, may be DateTime has some problem... Also should GMT-00 be GMT-00:00

Comment: Dhrubajyoti, thanks, I added the extra :00 to the end of the string and that took care of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The position 25 indicates the beginning of the `GMT` part which is the one you are trying parse using the letter `z`. If you are sure that your time zone will always be `GMT`, then you can put it as a fixed string as the following:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT'
```

If the input time zone will differ from time to time, then separate it.

```
String zone = inputTime.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
```

And set the time zone in a separate line using `zone` string